# Event on new data load

Tags: javascript, web, events, frontend

Is there any event that happens when new data is loaded? For example, when new data is loaded in the feed of social media sites such as Facebook, does any event fire on that?

Comment: They are generally using websockets to check for new events. Or scheduling a scan from time to time using 'ajax'.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL is developed by Facebook, and you can find some of that aspect from this [link](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/7-subscriptions/)

This type of behavior is achieved by websockets most likely. For example, you can emit an event when a document is created in the database using Socket.io, and subscribe to the emitted event to show the new data. You can find more information from this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_event_handling.htm)